# Probability of 3 semi-specific coin flips

Tags: probability

If you flip three fair coins, what is the probability that you'll get heads on the first two flips and tails on the last flip?

Can I produce a table for this problem? I tried, but failed. For example, if we let T1 be a result of a Tail for the first flip, and H2 be a result of a Head for the second flip, and so on, I can come up with the following 6 possibilities:

1. T1 + H2
2. T1 + H3
3. T2 + H1
4. T2 + H3
5. T3 + H1
6. T3 + H2

However, I understand that from the 1/2 probability of the first flip, the 1/2 of the second and third flips:
1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2 = 1/8

We have 8 possibilities. I can easily produce a table for the above 6 possibilities, but what are the other 2 possibilities that I haven't mentioned and how can I design a table that shows all said 8 possibilities?

If that is not possible, drawing a table for said possibilities, then what other visual aid can I use to help me understand this problem and all its possibilities? I really like tables for most probability problems because they really help me understand all the possibilities, how they come about, how to highlight the solutions in a table and I love to see the patterns that said solutions sometimes draw in a table should we shade / highlight them.

Comment: Not following your list.  The eight possibilities are $TTT,TTH,THT, HTT, THH,HTH,HHT,HHH$.

Comment: Why do you call the flips "semi-specific"? Each of them is specific.

Comment: The eight possibilities correspond to a "table" in the form of a [unit cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_cube), whose corners are the outcomes, the coordinates being coded, for example, as $T=0,H=1$. Unfortunately, for more than three flips, we would need to visualize [hypercubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube).

Comment: @lulu Thank you. My mistake was that I was using letters for only 2 flips at a time, being confined by the idea of a 2-dimensional table.

Comment: @Théophile I was thinking that both the first and second flips wanted are heads, thus confused that with flexibility and lack of uniqueness.

Comment: @r.e.s. Thank you. This explains my confusion trying to come up with a table for a 3-dimensional problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can draw a tree diagram like the graph below. This helps to get all possible outcomes.

[image]

**Remark**

Tossing 3 coins once at the same time is equally like tossing 1 coin three times. You can replace the ith toss in the diagram by the ith coin.

Comment: Thank you. I was really hoping there was a way to represent that problem using a table, but I understand now that's not possible because it's a 3-dimensional problem. This also explains my attempts of representing the flips with only 2 letters. I saw those diagrams before and didn't like them, but when you put the outcomes in 3-lettered combinations like that, I definitely like it as much as I like tables for 2-dimensional probability problems. This opens my mind up to the possibility of using that diagram effectively, rather than disliking it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The result of a coin flip is either H or T.
Therefore the result of 3 coinflips is going to be a 3 letter word where each letter is either a H or a T. 
There are  $2\cdot2\cdot2 = 8$ of these words for the same reason -namely that each letter can be a "T" or a "H".

You are looking for the outcome of "HHT", there's only one way to get that.

So the probabilty of getting a "HHT" is $\frac{1}{8}$.

Or you can say that the coinflips are independent so

P(outcome is"HHT") = P(1st coin is H, 2nd coin is H, 3rd coin is T) = P(first coin is H)P(second coin is H)P(third coin is T) = $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thank you very much. This does clarify a lot for me. I wish there was a way to pick two answers as a composite answer overall.